# The difference of conda, pip and pip3 in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I want to know the specific difference between conda, pip and pip3. Specifically, in Anaconda (Python version=3.6), the package of “## + list” is not the same, and I do not find any problems with the alternate use of these installation tools. But I still don't know exactly where these packages are installed, and what's more important is whether they cause conflicts.

Comment: What are you specifically asking here? i.e. is this about the purpose of those tools or their environments on your local system?

Comment: This question has many duplicates on StackOverflow. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda?rq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158543/best-practices-with-pip-and-conda-for-consistency/49162977#49162977 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471477/python-package-can-be-installed-by-pip-but-not-conda/45486051?s=2|87.5032#45486051 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917541/what-is-the-effect-of-using-pip-to-install-python-packages-on-anaconda/45919845?s=6|64.9264#45919845

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between pip and conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda)